# Add some li elements to ul using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I have to add some li elements to a ul list.
Each li elements contain:

- one anchor
- one img tag

The problem is that the image is not displayed.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/michelejs/hxA9r/

```
function echoImages(json) {
    alert(json);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
    var html = "";
    $.each(obj, function() {
        html += '<li id ="menu_travel-store" class="space ">' + '<a href="' + this['redirectURL'] + '">' + '<img src="' + this['imageURL'] + '" />' + this['description'] + '</a>' + '</li>';
    });
    alert(html);
    $("#cityOffers").append(html);
}​
```

I have seen that Chrome add this css property:

```
display: none !important;
visibility: hidden !important;
opacity: 0 !important;
background-position: 0px 0px;
```

but if I delete it with developer tools the image is not still showed.

What is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: The images are displayed for me. Which browser?

Comment: in chrome it's woking for me

Comment: I get no images in FireFox

Comment: It's not working for me in Firefox 17.0.1

Comment: Working for me both on FF & Chrome :)

Comment: @michele - images are not loading in my chrome as well ! and firefox loads that images !

Comment: This sounds like a hosting problem.

Comment: Why some of us see the images and some not?

Comment: @michele - when i clicked `Run` button of jsFiddle, The css property you mentioned in Question is getting removed !

Comment: @Pankit Kapadia I have not understand.....

Answer (score 2):

Solved,the problem is AdBlock Chrome extension that block the image loading.....

Answer (score 0):

you use the wrong jQuery function use

`$("#cityOffers").html(html);`

instead of

`$("#cityOffers").append(html);`

html() expect a string containing HTML code while append() expect a dom object

Comment: No he doesn't. That will overwrite existing html within the element.

Comment: From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/append/): "content  DOM element, **HTML string**, or jQuery object to insert at the end of each element in the set of matched elements."

Comment: i know that html() replace the code inside the element but in this case it's correct to replace the content i think, i was sure that append() requires a DOM object my bad

Answer (score 0):

I tested in firefox and it works.

I have structured your code a little better.

http://jsfiddle.net/hxA9r/4/

```
function echoImages(json) {
    alert(json);
    var obj = $.parseJSON(json);
    var html = "";
    $.each(obj, function () {
        html += '<li id ="menu_travel-store" class="space ">' + '<a href="' + this.redirectURL + '">' + '<img src="' + this.imageURL + '" />' + this.description + '</a>' + '</li>';
    });
    alert(html);
    $("#cityOffers").append(html);
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    data = '[{"id":"1","redirectURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/1.png","imageURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/1.png","title":"1","description":"1"},{"id":"3","redirectURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/3.png","imageURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/3.png","title":"3","description":"3"},{"id":"6","redirectURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/9.png","imageURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/9.png","title":"9","description":"9"},{"id":"2","redirectURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/2.png","imageURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/2.png","title":"2","description":"2"},{"id":"5","redirectURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/5.png","imageURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/5.png","title":"5","description":"5"},{"id":"4","redirectURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/4.png","imageURL":"http:\/\/www.judopassion.com\/affiliate\/images\/4.png","title":"4","description":"4"}]';
    echoImages(data);

});​
```

**EDIT:** This sounds like a problem accessing the images from the host. I've tested on multiple browsers old and new and it runs fine.

Comment: in my chrome I don't see any images...img element is added but I think it is hidden...what may be wrong? thanks